# Conditionally Enable Face Attribute in a Terminal

Tags: faces

I'm currently trying to *conditionally* change the face attributes of two faces related to [dap-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode) while running Emacs in server-mode inside a terminal (using -nw):

```
    (defun my-dap-terminal-hook ()
      (unless (display-graphic-p)
        (set-face-attribute 'dap-ui-pending-breakpoint-face nil
                            :slant 'italic
                            :background "#ffe4e1")
        (set-face-attribute 'dap-ui-verified-breakpoint-face nil
                            :weight 'bold
                            :slant 'italic
                            :background "#ffebcd")))
    (add-hook 'dap-mode-hook #'my-dap-terminal-hook)
```

Adding this to my `init.el` file 'works', but I need to restart the frame for the face changes to take effect, which is quite annoying. Is there some way to trigger some kind of redraw or update of all faces?

Answer (score 0):

And 5 minutes after writing up the question I found the answer to my specific problem: I used the wrong hook. The faces are not properly created until `dap-ui.el` has been loaded, so they are not set properly. The correct way would be to add the function to the `dap-ui-mode-hook` instead:

```
(add-hook 'dap-ui-mode-hook #'my-dap-terminal-hook)
```